# Python sum function concatenating lists

Tags: python, sum

When try `sum([1,3],[3,6])` in python, I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

but when I try `sum([[1,3],[3,6]],[])`, I get [1, 3, 3, 6] output.

Can someone please explain this python behavior?

Comment: Did you check the [`sum()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)? There is a second `start` argument and it defaults to `0`.

Comment: `import itertools; itertools.chain([1,3], [3,6])` , It will help you.

Comment: actually sum() method has two parameter, first parameter is iterable like list, tuple and dict and the second param is start which is optional param. In your `sum([[1,3],[3,6]],[])` your first param is good i.e. `[[1,3],[3,6]]` and second param is just `[]` thats why second one is giving you the intended output. for more detail see https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/sum

Comment: Thanks.. that explains it :)